# Замена символа в строке в Python

Tags: python

Задание, котрое нужно сделать в python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что я сделал.

```
s="у лукоморья 123 дуб зеленый 456"

print(s)

print(s.index('я')) #1

print(s.count('у')) #2

if s.isalpha():

    print("Только из букв")

else:

    print(str.capitalize(s)) #3

print(len(s)) 

if len(s)>4:

    print(str.lower(s)) #4
```

Подскажите, как сделать пункт 5.

Comment: Замените изображения текстом.

Comment: Для работы со строками есть куча встроенных методов, в 5 пункте нужен метод replace()

Comment: `s = 'О' + s[1:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строки в python неизменяемы, поэтому вы не можете рассматривать их как список и присваивать индексы.

Используйте .replace():

```
line = line.replace(';', ':')
```

Если вам нужно заменить только определенные точки с запятой, вам нужно быть более конкретным. Вы можете использовать нарезку, чтобы изолировать секцию строки для замены в:

```
line = line[:10].replace(';', ':') + line[10:]
```

Это заменит все точки с запятой в первых 10 символах строки.